# Confusing function documentation and contract?

Tags: java

Lets say I have helper (util) methods and caller

Helper methods:

```
public int getSomeIntermediateResult(String someString){
     // Some operations with someString.
     int x = ... ; //Not a constant, but assume it gets created with some computation in method.
     return x;
}

public int overallHelperFunction(String someString){
     int intermediateResult = getSomeIntermediateResult(someString);
     return getFinalOverallResult(someString, intermediateResult);
}

// THIS FUNCTION MUST only be called with the {someString} 
// AND the intermediateResult created by getSomeIntermediateResult(someString) only, otherwise it makes no sense. 
public int getFinalOverallResult(String someString, int intermediateResult){
   // .. donSome Other Stuff and return
}
```

Here is he trouble I am having, I have two callers

```
public int callerOne(String someString){
  return overallHelperFunction(someString);
}
```

This one is fine, I can directly call `overallHelperFunction` which takes care of everything.
The second one is the issue.

```
public int callerTwo(String someString){
   int intermediate = getIntermediateResult(someString);
   int finalResult = getFinallOverallResult(someString, intermediate);
   return intermediate + finalResult; // I have to REUSE intermediate here.
}
```

Now this is the main issue.

The thing is the function `getFinallOverallResult` doesn't make sense if its called with two disjoint `someString` and `intermediateResult` so make it a `public` interface is risky if it gets in the hands of a wrong caller, but at the same time, I need it exposed for `callerTwo`. What should I do in this case? I did document `getFinallOverallResult`, but there is no actual restriction of it being called with random params.

Thanks!

Comment: Put the callerOne and callerTwo methods in the utility class and make the getIntermediateResult and getFinalOverallResult methods private?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc, the issue is, those methods are technically not utilities, which is the main struggle I'm having.

Comment: Then don't call it utility, call it facade or something. Anyways, you want to ensure some code is executed in a specific way. This is when you make it private and create a facade which uses the hidden code as it's supposed to. [Facade Design Pattern in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-facade-pattern)

Comment: *GIGO (Garbage In, Garbage Out).* If the caller of your API calls it wrong, i.e. with garbage, then they will get garbage back. It is always up to the caller to adhere to any restrictions documented for your methods. --- It like when you sort a `List` and pass in a `Comparator`. If you violate the rules defined for a `Comparator`, then the result will be undefined. You cannot prevent misuse. --- To make sure (well, improve the probability) that the caller reads you restrictions, **change the comment to be javadoc**. --- If they ignore your instructions, then they get to live with it.